# I face some problem while I try to install axios via npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

up to date, audited 1446 packages in 7s

194 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: Everything looks okay to me, assuming you did ```npm install axios```. 
Then, you can run ```npm audit``` as stated in the message to check for eventual security vulnerabilities in your installed packages.

Comment: yeh I did all steps but I did not Inderstand  what "6 high severity vulnerabilities" mean

Comment: It means that some packages may contain vulnerabilities, so you aware. It won't break your code. You can run ```npm audit fix``` to try to fix them.

Comment: thank a lot my Friend for your help

Comment: @PatriceThimothee it means specified packages do contain high severity vulnerabilities. How could that look 'okey' to you? The "run: npm audit fix --force" message is obviously from npm audit. In my case it only makes situation much worse (It results with 69 vulnerabilities, 35 high.).

Comment: @Denis, I was saying vulnerabilities will not stop them from working on their code. I am assuming that the OP is starting with Node as It's a recurrent question. I have added an answer for lack of space in the comment section (My comment was extended to go deeper).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, we should address these vulnerabilities, especially in stages like production, sensible workplaces, etc. However, often, you will have to address these vulnerabilities manually.

`npm audit fix` will try to "fix" what it can by performing some updates.

`npm audit fix --force` will try to go further in considering upgrading even between major semantic versions (2 to 3, for instance, instead of 2 to 2.1 if necessary)

It may not be enough. To be on the safer side, you look through every single module declared vulnerable to ponder eventual risks and how any  issues can affect your project(s)

Keep in mind:
"npm" can find vulnerabilities absolutely at any time.

Therefore, if the developer has not sent a new version correcting the identified problem, you will have to:

- Decide whether to use a new library.
- Decide to downgrade or upgrade their libraries with the most negligible effect on your code.
- Decide to fix the vulnerability yourself
- Decide to wait for the author to fix the issue
- Decide to implement your solution.
- Decide to live with these vulnerabilities and likely address them before production.

`npm audit` monitors modules over time, so some vulnerabilities can still happen on perfectly thought-safe modules. Therefore, there is no 100% permanent fixing.

A way to have the list of problematic modules:

```bash
$> npm audit fix --dry-run --json
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-audit